# Expected primary-expression before"int" - C

Tags: c

Estou com o seguinte erro no meu código: `expected primary-expression before"int"`

```
 #include<stdio.h>
        #include<stdlib.h>

        void imc(float massa_corporal[3], float peso[3], float altura[3], int i){
            for (i=0; i<3; i++){
            printf ("\nInforme seu peso: ");
            scanf ("%f", &peso[i]);

            printf ("Informe sua altura: ");
            scanf ("%f", &altura[i]);

            massa_corporal[i]= peso[i] / (altura[i]*altura[i]); 
            }

            for (i=0; i<3; i++){
            printf ("imc[%d]= %f\n",i , massa_corporal[i]);
            }
        }

        int main(){
            float massa_corporal[3], peso[3], altura[3];
            int i;
            imc (massa_corporal[3], peso[3], altura[3], int i);
        }
```

Comment: Qual a linha onde o erro esta ocorrendo?

Comment: linha 25, na chamada da função IMC.

Comment: Basta tirar o int na chamada da função. Agora: qual o sentido de você passar como parâmetro uma variável que só será utilizada de forma auxiliar (apenas um índice) no corpo da função? Você tem que chamar a função da forma: imc (massa_corporal, peso, altura,  i); pois senão estará se referindo a um item específico do array, que, por sinal, estará fora dos limites do array.

Comment: Comente no final da linha com erro `// erro aqui`, pq não tem nem 25 linhas de código nesse trecho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você está fazendo confusão entre declaração de vetor e passagem de vetor como parâmetro.

Quando você declara o vetor com `float massa_corporal[3], peso[3], altura[3];` o programa entende que você está criando 3 vetores de 3 posições cada.

Porém, quando você envia para a função um `massa_corporal[3]` está tentando passar **especificamente** a 4ª posição, que não existe (lembre-se que seu vetor tem a posição 0, 1 e 2, apenas). Assim, o correto é omitir essa redeclaração no momento de chamar a função.

Da mesma forma você pode remover a especificação do tamanho na chamada da função. Dito isto, o correto é:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void imc(float massa_corporal[], float peso[], float altura[], int i){
    for (i=0; i<3; i++){
    printf ("\nInforme seu peso: ");
    scanf ("%f", &peso[i]);

    printf ("Informe sua altura: ");
    scanf ("%f", &altura[i]);

    massa_corporal[i]= peso[i] / (altura[i]*altura[i]); 
    }

    for (i=0; i<3; i++){
    printf ("imc[%d]= %f\n",i , massa_corporal[i]);
    }
}

int main (){
    float massa_corporal[3], peso[3], altura[3];
    int i;
    imc (massa_corporal, peso, altura, i);
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, agora entendi, estava um pouco perdido em relação ao uso de funções.